# Equilibrium radius of a charged drop

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-statics, surface-tension

We learnt about the equilibrium a charged **bubble** would assume due to the suface tension and the electrostatic pressure.
$$\frac{4T}{R}=\frac{{\sigma}^2}{2{\epsilon}_o}$$
Where $T$ is the surface tension of the liquid, $R$ is the radius of the bubble and  $\sigma$ is the surface charge density.

---

I was wondering if I could extend this to a **spherical drop** with a volume charge density $\rho$.

I have a problem in finding the electrostatic pressure on the surface of the drop. Could someone help me?

---

Edit: Okay this question was closed for some reason, so I am going to make it more clear.

My question was basically, you have a uniformly charged drop, having a volume charge density $\rho$ and has a surface tension $T$. What I need to find is the electrostatic pressure at the surface so that I can equate that to the Surface tension values, thus getting the equilibrium radius.

I know its been too long now, but I am still curious about the result.

Hope this makes the question more clear.

Comment: I an new here so I don't know why this question was closed?

Comment: I just wanted to know the electrostatic pressure at the surface of a uniformly charged sphere

Comment: Try asking a new question, show your work and where you get stuck.

Comment: In the question, either avoid or try to explain what you mean by electrostatic pressure and how it differs from total pressure.